# Locked out of admin account; but the password is right in shell; password changed too!

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, login-screen

I have a dual boot, win 7 and the latest lts 12.xx. I tried logging into my regular account but it keeps refusing to open. There is no message saying anything was incorrect, but that message still comes up if I type in gibberish as a password.

I initially thought that changing password would help, even though I could access my files by using the correct one in shell through recovery mode. **So I did change using 'passwd'.** But the result is the same. I cannot open my desktop, just shell which I dont know too much about when it comes to transferring files between partitions

SIDE NOTE:
I made a guest account for people to use when I am not around without a password. But decided to put in a simple password later through the 'users'(i think thats the name) program in the settings menu. But the changes did not take place and I am still unable to add the password even though everything runs fine while adding and adjusting priveleges. Maybe the two things are related???

Comment: If you did `sudo passwd` you changed the _root_ account's password not your account.

Comment: I actually tried this: >mount -rw -o remount / > passwd <username>...should I try changing it again with a sudo?

Comment: No, you shouldn't.  Try looking at [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/24006/44179) question.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to recovery mode, and choose to drop to root shell.

```
# cat /etc/passwd
```

you should see a return like this:

> root@TOSHIBA:~# cat /etc/passwd
>
> root:**x**:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash

if you get that **x** after root, then shadow file contains the root password.

do:

```
# nano /etc/shadow
```

scroll to your user account, and remove everything between the first set of ":"

change this:

> denis:$6$9eL.6v0I$Ze6X0970H/DC5vlH/9tOMWtSoHpqHXzbUX1v7Z.Nozf/p5SriiRU12WPzBsGJ4SsxRhl.6uSHdcbtAAnWCTyb0:15680:0:99999:7:::

to this:

> denis::15680:0:99999:7:::

Hit CTRL + O to save

and

Hit CTRL + X to exit

Reboot.

Comment: I do see an X in front of root, but the lines in nano looks like- username:x:1000:1000:username,,,:/home/username:/bin/hash  - this is the only line with the username, so should it look like it does? And how should I modify it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake. Second command is "sudo nano /etc/shadow"

Comment: This did not work for me. The effect of deleting the long string after the username (denis in the example) in `/etc/shadow` is that the user gets logged in without having a password asked. Like a guest user. I think this is undesirable in most cases.